# How to properly allocate memory for this linked list

Tags: c++, memory, linked-list, allocation

I can't seem to find where I'm going wrong with the memory allocation. All the functions work properly, but the program crashes randomly throughout its execution. I know the error is with how I'm allocating memory for the linked list, but I just can't seem to figure out which part is wrong.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
void menu_function(void);
void command_execute(string command, string name1, string name2);
int hash_function(string str);
void insert_into_hashtable(int ascii_total, string name);
void add_friendship(int ascii_key, string name);
void print_friendships(int aascii_key);
void check_friendship(int ascii_key, string name);
void remove_friendship(int ascii_key, string name);

#define SIZE 125

struct friend_list {
    string name = "";
    struct friend_list * next;
};

typedef struct friend_list list;

struct user {
    string name;
    int key;
    friend_list * FriendList;
};

struct user * hashArray[SIZE];

int main(int argc,
    const char * argv[]) {

    menu_function();
    return 0;
}

void menu_function() {
    char user_input[100]; //this could limit the size of input
    string command;
    string name1 = "\0";
    string name2 = "\0";;
    char * token; ** strong text **
        int inputsize = 100;
    int i = 0;
    char delimit[] = " \t\r\n\v\f";
    while (1) {
        printf("\nP <Name> to create a person\n");
        printf("F <Name> <Name> record friendship\n");
        printf("U <Name> <Name> terminate friendship\n");
        printf("L <Name> print out friends of a specified person\n");
        printf("Q <Name> <Name>  check friendship status of two people\n");
        printf("X - terminate the progarm\n");

        // Determine user input and
        fgets(user_input, inputsize, stdin);
        //getline(&input, &inputsize, stdin);//takes in user input;

        //printf("input: %s", user_input);

        //parsing the string for the data within
        token = strtok(user_input, delimit);
        i = 0;
        while (token != NULL) {
            if (i == 0) {
                command = token;
                //cout<< command<<endl;
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                name1 = token;
                // cout<< name1<<":"<<endl;
            }
            if (i == 2) {
                name2 = token;
                //  cout<< name2<<":"<<endl;
                name1 = name1 + "\n";
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            i++;
        }
        command_execute(command, name1, name2);
        command = '\0';
        name1 = '\0';
        name2 = '\0';
    }
}

void command_execute(string command, string name1, string name2) {
    //cout<<"command is: "<<command<<endl;

    switch (command[0]) {

    case 'P': //Create record of the person
        insert_into_hashtable(hash_function(name1), name1);
        break;
    case 'F': //Record friendship
        add_friendship(hash_function(name1), name2);
        add_friendship(hash_function(name2), name1);
        break;
    case 'U': //Terminate Friendship
        remove_friendship(hash_function(name1), name2);
        remove_friendship(hash_function(name2), name1);
        break;
    case 'L': //Print out the persons Friends
        print_friendships(hash_function(name1));
        break;
    case 'Q': //Check on friendship
        check_friendship(hash_function(name1), name2);
        break;
    case 'X': //Exit the program **** COMPLETED
        exit(1);
        break;

    default:
        cout << "Error occured based on your command please try again" << endl;
        break;
    }
}

int hash_function(string string) {
    //going to use the ASCI value of the name with different weights per array position to hash the names
    int ascii_key = 0;
    int ascii_total = 0;
    // cout<< string.length()<< endl;
    //cout<< string<< endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length() - 1; i++) {
        ascii_total = (int) string[i] * (i * 3 + 1);
        //   cout<< string[i]<< endl;
    }
    ascii_key = ascii_total % SIZE;
    //deals with colisions through open hashing
    while (hashArray[ascii_key] != NULL && strcmp(hashArray[ascii_key] - > name.c_str(), string.c_str())) { //strcmp(hashArray[ascii_key]->name.c_str(), string.c_str())
        //hashArray[ascii_key] != NULL ||
        ascii_key++;
    }

    // ****** decide size of the hash table and then finished hashing function. Usually hash time is gonna be half full
    cout << ascii_key << endl;

    return ascii_key;
}

void insert_into_hashtable(int ascii_key, string name) {
    int k = 0;
    //get the hash key
    user * item = (user * ) malloc(sizeof(struct user));
    item - > name = name;
    item - > key = ascii_key;
    item - > FriendList = NULL;
    cout << ascii_key << endl;
    //collisions resolved by linear probing
    //store the user in the table

    hashArray[ascii_key] = item;
    k++;
    //free(item);
}

void add_friendship(int ascii_key, string name) {
    //gonna have to check for valid input on users
    list * add = (list * ) malloc(sizeof(struct friend_list));
    add - > name = name;
    add - > next = NULL;
    if (ascii_key == 13) {
        ascii_key = ascii_key;
    }
    /* if( hashArray[ascii_key]->FriendList->next == NULL )
     {
     cout<<hashArray[ascii_key]->FriendList<<endl;
     hashArray[ascii_key]->FriendList = temp;
     }
     else*/
    {
        add - > next = hashArray[ascii_key] - > FriendList;
        hashArray[ascii_key] - > FriendList = add;

    }
    free(add);
}

void print_friendships(int ascii_key) {
    friend_list * temp = (friend_list * ) malloc(sizeof(friend_list));
    temp = hashArray[ascii_key] - > FriendList;
    while (temp != NULL) {

        cout << temp - > name << endl;
        if (temp - > next == NULL) {
            free(temp);
            return;
        }
        temp = temp - > next;

    }
    //free(temp);
}

void check_friendship(int ascii_key, string name) {
    list * temp = (list * ) malloc(sizeof(struct friend_list));
    temp = hashArray[ascii_key] - > FriendList;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(temp - > name.c_str(), name.c_str()) == 0) {
            cout << "Friendship exist" << endl;
            return;
        }
        temp = temp - > next;
    }
    cout << "No Record of Friendship" << endl;
    free(temp);
}

//need to finish
void remove_friendship(int ascii_key, string name) {
    list * temp = (list * ) malloc(sizeof(struct friend_list));
    list * prev = (list * ) malloc(sizeof(struct friend_list));
    temp = hashArray[ascii_key] - > FriendList;

    if (temp != NULL && temp - > name == name) {
        hashArray[ascii_key] - > FriendList = temp - > next; // Changed head
        // free old head
        return;
    }

    //not the head
    while (temp != NULL && temp - > name != name) {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp - > next;
    }
    if (temp == NULL) return;

    // Unlink the node from linked list
    prev - > next = temp - > next;
    free(temp);
    free(prev);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's probably lots of errors, but this is a big one

```
    user *item = (user*) malloc(sizeof(struct user));
```

should be

```
    user *item = new user;
```

In C++ you should **always** use `new`. The difference between `new` and `malloc` is that `malloc` does not call any constructors. So in your `user` object the constructor for the `string name` does not get called. So you have undefined behaviour (i.e. potential crashes) whenever you try to use `name`. And as stated in the comments, you should also be using `delete` not `free` for basically the same reason.

Having looked a bit more at the code there are lots and lots of pointer related bugs. For instance how about this

```
list* temp  = (list*)malloc(sizeof(struct friend_list));
temp = hashArray[ascii_key]->FriendList;
```

Forget about malloc vs new for a bit, and just look at the above code. You have a pointer `temp` which you make point to some allocated memory. Then you throw away that memory and make `temp` point at `hashArray[ascii_key]->FriendList` instead. What's the point of allocating the memory, if you don't use it? Then you compound the error by freeing the memory at the end of the function.

```
free(temp);
```

but `temp` no longer points at the allocated memory (because you made it point at the friend list instead). It's clear that you really haven't understand pointers and memory allocation yet.

Here's how you should write that function

```
void check_friendship( int ascii_key, string name)
{
    list* temp = hashArray[ascii_key]->FriendList;
    while( temp != NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(temp->name.c_str(), name.c_str()) == 0)
        {
            cout<<"Friendship exist"<<endl;
            return;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout<<"No Record of Friendship"<<endl;
}
```

See **no allocation at all**. I guess you have some kind of rule in your head, whereever there's a pointer I must allocate some memory. That's not true, allocation is about creating new objects. `check_friendship` does not create any new objects (it only checks existing ones) so it doesn't need to allocate or free anything.

`remove_friendship` has the same issue, since it is removing a friendship it should `delete` one object, (the friendship being removed) but there's no reason for it to allocate anything.

`add_friendship` has the same error but in reverse. `add_friendship` should allocate one new object for the friendship being added, you do that, but then you try and free the object at the end of the function. You're operating under some kind of blanket rule that every pointer variable must be allocated and then freed instead of thinking logically about what objects each function needs to create or destroy.

Comment: Don't forget to replace `free` by `delete` as well.

Comment: That fixed my memory issue but now my add_function isnt working properly. Do you see anything wrong with that logic?

Comment: Not immediately (apart from the errors already pointed out). Do you know how to use a debugger? Best tool for resolving this kind of bug.